# How to make offset anchor function for a specific anchor?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
function offsetAnchor() {
    if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 160);
    }
}

       $(window).on("hashchange",offsetAnchor);

       window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 1);
```

and when i click an anchor, it leads me to the anchor -160 pixels, which is correct. however, each anchor on my page needs a specific offset.

How do i specify the function to act on only a certain anchor? is there a way to give multiple offsets to multiple anchors all within one function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about refactoring that code a little bit like this:

```
var anchorDistanceMap = {
    "someAnchor": -160,
    "otherAnchor": -400
};

function offsetAnchor(distance) {
    if (location.hash.length !== 0) {
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - distance);
    }
}

$(window).on("hashchange", function (e) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        offsetAnchor(anchorDistanceMap[location.hash]);
    }, 1);
});
```

And then you just have to edit the `anchorDistanceMap` object to represent the distance necessary for each anchor.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm having trouble trying to figure out what to input in the "someAnchor" and "otherAnchor" locations. I'm a pretty big JS newb. For example, this is the HTML of one of the links I want to offset. 
     <a id="hammenu" class="blacktext quickfade"      href="home.html#graybox.html">ABOUT</a>

Let me know if you can help, thank you.

Comment: That object maps which distance you want to jump (offset) for each anchor on your page.

Comment: Okay thanks so much, I got it working but now i have one last question. Say i want  my anchor called "otherAnchor" to be exempt from the function, and scroll to its standard location on the page. How do i either 1: exempt "otherAnchor" from the function, or 2: what value do i input into the anchorDistanceMap for the "otherAnchor" to make it go to its default location on the page?